# redirect to log in each time when page is opened in any browser tab angular-oauth-oidc

Tags: angular6, identityserver4, angular-oauth2-oidc

I want users to redirect to log in each time they open Angular 6 SPA that is secured with identity sever as authorization server with angular-oauth-oidc.

I am using OAuth 2.0 implicit flow for users to log in with Angular SPA.

I tried with clearing sessionStorage or localStorage but It is not working.
How can I implement above using this library ?

```
this.oauthService.configure(authConfig);
this.oauthService.tokenValidationHandler = new JwksValidationHandler();
this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin().then(() => {
  // If there is a valid access token
  if (this.oauthService.hasValidAccessToken()) {
  }
});
```

Comment: Set `prompt=login` ([see documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/endpoints/authorize.html)) to disable SSO. Otherwise the user may be authenticated automatically.

Comment: could this be possible from client side like using auth config for amgular-oauth2-oidc ?